# Transparent Background in an image

Tags: graphics, export, animation, opacity

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow change the background of the result of a plot function so that whenever I paste it in a movie editor, it will be transparent (not white). An example code is:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x t], {x, 0, 2 Pi }], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Here, the background is white. I would like it to be transparent.

**EDIT**

I tried (simplified example code):

```
test = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background-> None]
Export["test.jpg", test]
```

this resulted in:

[image: planets]

Is there any way of saving the file with a transparent background? Maybe the file extension is wrong?

Comment: `Animate[Plot[Sin[x t], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> None], {t, 0, 1}]` ?

Comment: does this give what you need: `testframe = RemoveBackground[Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]
Export["testframe.png", testframe]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, this is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should specify `Background -> None` for `Export` and use an image format which supports transparency:

```
test = Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
file = Export["test.png", test, Background -> None];
```

The exported image has an alpha channel:

```
img = Import[file];
ImageMeasurements[img, "Transparency"]
img // AlphaChannel
```

> ```
> True
> ```
>
> [image: output]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow change the background of the
> result of a plot function

one option is to use `Background` option

```
Plot[Sin[x ], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adjust the color as needed.

You can add `Opacity` as follows

```
 Plot[Sin[x ], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> Directive[Opacity[.2], Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all. The question was whether there is an option that exports the graphic/animation such that it has a transparent background. Background -> None doesn't do this for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Both jpeg(jpg) and png seems to be non-transparent, at least by default and without some extra tricks. If you save as PDF, which is transparent, you can render to pixels in, e.g., Photoshop, and maintain transparency and save as png.